# elasticsearch aggregation and get columns value

Tags: elasticsearch

want to get the values ​​of the bps and pps columns over time through aggregation. Now, if you use my query, you can only get a count of it. If there is a way to get the value of a specific column according to the interval value

this's my code

```
<code>
 "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "reg-date",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "2018-10-01T00:00:00",
          "max": "2018-10-07T23:59:59"
        }
      }
    }
  }
</code>
```

Is there a way I want to get a value that is not the number of specific columns that satisfy this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the "value" of a single field once aggregated doesn't make sense anymore - if your one-day aggregation has three documents, then a single field doesn't have one "value" anymore over that one-day period.

Instead you can use a sub-aggregation to compute an aggregate value for the day, such as a sum or average:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "reg-date",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "2018-10-01T00:00:00",
          "max": "2018-10-07T23:59:59"
        }
      },
      # sub-aggregations
      "aggs": {
        "bps_average": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "bps"
          }
        },
        "pps_average": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "pps"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then each bucket will have fields `bps_average` and `pps_average`. If you replace `avg` with `sum` you'll get a sum instead, and there are [many other metrics aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html).

The ElasticSearch guide has a good [section on aggregations and nesting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_buckets_inside_buckets.html).

Comment: it's good work thank you     if you know can i give some link like this query

Comment: @Hello I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Do you have a site or link that contains information about the query?

Comment: @Hello - the ElasticSearch guide is probably the best resource here, as often. I added a link to the relevant section in my answer.